# Tensorflow installation with anaconda installation and run issue

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I have been trying to install Tensorflow for a really long time now, but I never seem to make it work. I have tried to install Tensorflow via pip, virtual environment and anaconda so far. The installation process seem to run smoothly with all three methods. But as soon as I try to validate the installation by running "import tensorflow" I get the following error. I know it looks kind of chaotic, I wasn't sure how to pose the question.

By now, all help is appreciated

Thanks

[image: Terminal window]

Comment: reffer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40884668/installing-tensorflow-on-windows-python-3-6-x ... You should use Python 3.5.2 and not 3.6.x

Comment: Please check this thread
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41991101/importerror-libcudnn-when-running-a-tensorflow-program
This solves the same import error issue

Comment: Ok thanks a lot guys, this installation process has been like a jungle to me. I have already spent way too much time on this.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, you have to install python 3.5.X first

Secondly, I strongly recommend you to use anaconda. You should install anaconda 4.4.0 for python 3.6 version and 64-bit installer.

Then, you should run the following command

conda create -n tensorflow python=3.5

By the way, would you watch the [tensorflow installation tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xY8NAxD37mc) ?

Answer (score 1):

TensorFlow versions 1.2 and later **are** compatible with Python 3.6. The error message points to the actual problem:

> ImportError: libcudnn.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

This implies two things:

1. You have installed the `tensorflow-gpu` package, which requires a CUDA-capable GPU and a working installation of CUDA and cuDNN.
2. TensorFlow cannot find cuDNN.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41991101/3574081) explains how to fix your cuDNN installation.

Answer (score -1):

Update:

I get a similar error but the message in the bottom is now:

"ImportError libnvidia-fatbinaryloader.so.384.47: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Also when I enter "which nvcc" it returns /usr/bin/nvcc

Comment: Please add your update to your original post by [editting](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45010115/edit) it. Answer only if you have an actual answer to the question.