# ImportError: libcudnn.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory Tensorflow

Tags: nvidia, tensorflow, cudnn

I cannot get it to work! Been trying for almost two days now. Installed Cuda8 and CuDnn 6 - didn't work. added the solution written in [ImportError: libcudnn when running a TensorFlow program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41991101/importerror-libcudnn-when-running-a-tensorflow-program) here.
The error I'm getting -

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "/home/shenath/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/shenath/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/shenath/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/home/shenath/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/home/shenath/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: libcudnn.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/shenath/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/home/shenath/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/home/shenath/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shenath/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/shenath/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/shenath/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/home/shenath/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/home/shenath/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: libcudnn.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

I am new to this. Any help will be really appreciated. If you need anymore info I'll be happy to provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure they are in the correct directory after you install `cuda` and `cudnn`.
Run the following command after installing `cudnn 6`. `Tensorflow` only checks the required file on you `cuda` directory. So we copy or link the required files from `cudnn` to that directory.

```
mkdir /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/include/ && \
  ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/include/cudnn.h /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/include/cudnn.h && \
  ln -s /usr/include/cudnn.h /usr/local/cuda/include/cudnn.h && \
  ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn.so /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn.so && 
  ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn.so.6 /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn.so.6
```

So, if you are still having that error make sure follow the steps [here](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/data-center/gpu-accelerated-applications/tensorflow/).

Comment: Thanks! for anyone else reading this what I did was - I  fresh install and followed the Nvidia link Ultraviolet posted. While installing libcupti-dev I noticed "/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/local/cuda-8.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcudnn.so.6 is not a symbolic link". What I had to do was type "sudo cp -P  cuda/include/cudnn.h /usr/local/cuda/include" and "sudo cp -P  cuda/lib64/libcudnn* /usr/local/cuda/lib64" instead of the instructions given on the Nvidia site. And now it's working properly!