# ImportError: libcudnn.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, ubuntu-16.04

I installed `Tensorflow 1.6.0` - GPU version with anaconda in a Python 3.6.4 environment.

When I do `import tensorflow as tf`, I get the following error:

```
ImportError: libcudnn.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The different versions:

- `cudnn : 7.1.1`
- `cuda : 9.0.176`
- `tensorflow : 1.6.0`
- `Ubuntu : 16.04`

I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42013316/after-building-tensorflow-from-source-seeing-libcudart-so-and-libcudnn-errors) but it did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed the `nvidia-cuda-toolkit` package:

```
$ sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

and it worked.

I did not find the solution nor on the tensorflow website nor on the nvidia installation page. I found it by luck while looking for a way to get the cuda version with a command line: [How to get the cuda version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727688/how-to-get-the-cuda-version)

Comment: Did not help for me.

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer is wrong (installing `nvidia-cuda-toolkit`). By installing the toolkit you are basically installing a second CUDA on top of already installed cuda from the nvidia guide.

The problem turned out to be an issue with symbolic links. Inspiration is from this topic http://queirozf.com/entries/installing-cuda-tk-and-tensorflow-on-a-clean-ubuntu-16-04-install
but the actual resolution is different

So at one point during `CuDNN` installation `nvidia` tutorial will ask you to do this:

```
sudo cp cuda/include/cudnn.h /usr/local/cuda/include
sudo cp cuda/lib64/libcudnn* /usr/local/cuda/lib64
sudo chmod a+r /usr/local/cuda/include/cudnn.h /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn*
```

The problem with this approach is that copying files with filter `libcudnn*` will break the symbolic links of the copied files. Instead, I suggest runnign following command, but it will still break the links:

```
sudo cp --preserve=links cuda/lib64/libcudnn* /usr/local/cuda/lib64
```

You can verify the links by running `ls -lha libcudnn*` in `/usr/local/cuda/lib64` folder. If you happen to not see a picture like this:

> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   13 May  2 20:02 libcudnn.so -> libcudnn.so.7
>
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   17 May  2 20:02 libcudnn.so.7 -> libcudnn.so.7.6.5
>
> -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 409M May  2 20:02 libcudnn.so.7.6.5
>
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 386M May  2 20:02 libcudnn_static.a

Then you just found the problem. The actual solution is involving doing the following:

```
sudo rm /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn.so
sudo rm /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn.so.7
cd /usr/local/cuda/lib64/
sudo ln -s libcudnn.so.7.6.5 libcudnn.so.7
sudo ln -s libcudnn.so.7 libcudnn.so
```

Remove the old "links" and create new ones. Verify the links again with `ls -lha libcudnn*`. After that run following command in verbose mode:

```
sudo ldconfig -v
```

**CHECK the logs.** I don't know exactly what it does, but it turned out that it is something very important. Also, if the log says that symbolic link is broken or something along these lines then the `tensorflow` will continue to show the error mentioned in the subject.

**BONUS!** make sure you have following paths appended as the last lines `nano ~/.bashrc`

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda/bin:/opt/nvidia/nsight-compute/2019.4.0${PATH:+:${PATH}}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
export CUDADIR=/usr/local/cuda${CUDADIR:+:${CUDADIR}}
export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda
```

and then run the command `source ~/.bashrc`

All of the above steps assume that you did NOT use the `nvidia-cuda-toolkit`, but instead used `nvidia` cuda repo.

Also when installing CUDA make sure you are not targeting the `10.2`. On the momenent of writing TF supports versions up to `Cuda 10.1`, so following is the right way of installing the necessary version:

```
sudo apt-cache policy cuda
sudo apt-get install cuda=10.1.243-1
```

Verifications by:

```
nvcc --version
nvidia-smi
```

**EDIT:** I found the error that you should AVOID seeing after running the `ldconfig` command:

> /usr/local/cuda-10.1/targets/x86_64-linux/lib:
>
> ...
>
> libnppist.so.10 -> libnppist.so.10.2.0.243
>
> libcuinj64.so.10.1 -> libcuinj64.so.10.1.243

**> /sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/local/cuda-10.1/targets/x86_64-linux/lib /libcudnn.so.7 is not a symbolic link**

> libcudnn.so.7 -> libcudnn.so.7.6.5
>
> libnppc.so.10 -> libnppc.so.10.2.0.243
>
> libnppicom.so.10 -> libnppicom.so.10.2.0.243
>
> libnvgraph.so.10 -> libnvgraph.so.10.1.243
>
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfakeroot:
>
> ...

If you see it, then something is still misconfigured.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputations to comment on Alex's answer. But now on Ubuntu 20.04 the paths have been changed! Also, no need to `--preserve=links` now when doing `cp`! So I should probably post a new answer:

Install cuDNN library 7.6 for TensorFlow 2.3.1 with CUDA 10.1, in an environment created by `conda create --name tfgpu10.1 python=3.8`:

1. Go to https://developer.nvidia.com/cuDNN
2. Download "cuDNN Library for Linux" in "Download cuDNN v7.6.5 (November 5th, 2019), for CUDA 10.1"
3. Extract using `tar -xvzf cudnn-10.1-linux-x64-v7.6.5.32.tgz`
4. "Install" files:

   ```sh
   sudo cp cuda/include/cudnn.h /usr/lib/cuda/include/
   sudo cp cuda/lib64/libcudnn* /usr/lib/cuda/lib64/
   ```
5. Set permission:

   ```sh
   sudo chmod a+r /usr/lib/cuda/include/cudnn.h /usr/lib/cuda/lib64/libcudnn*
   ```

Output of testing:

```py
Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  4 2020, 07:30:14) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
2020-12-02 03:58:41.089993: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
>>> tf.config.list_physical_devices("GPU")
2020-12-02 03:58:48.538295: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2020-12-02 03:58:48.587523: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-12-02 03:58:48.587838: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1716] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 1650 Ti computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.485GHz coreCount: 16 deviceMemorySize: 3.82GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 178.84GiB/s
2020-12-02 03:58:48.587860: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2020-12-02 03:58:48.589111: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
2020-12-02 03:58:48.590284: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2020-12-02 03:58:48.590488: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2020-12-02 03:58:48.591785: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2020-12-02 03:58:48.592520: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10
2020-12-02 03:58:48.595129: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2020-12-02 03:58:48.595213: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-12-02 03:58:48.595555: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-12-02 03:58:48.595815: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1858] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
```

Answer (score -5):

This didn't work for me, In my case it was because I had multiple versions of Cuda installed and that the cudnn version I had was for an older version than the one I was trying to use so I installed the cudnn for the new verision following nvidia's [instructions](http://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/cudnn-install/index.html) and that did it for me.

Comment: Please don't provide comment as an answer.