# tensorflow-gpu 1.8.0 ImportError: libcudnn.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow

I've just installed

Ubuntu 18.04

NVIDIA GPU driver 390

CUDA Toolkit version 9.0 (with all the patches)

CUDNN 7.0.5

followed this link
https://github.com/markjay4k/Install-Tensorflow-on-Ubuntu-17.10-/blob/master/Tensorflow%20Install%20instructions.ipynb

and instead of conda for tensorflow installation
I've used Virtualenv

and after installation, I couldn't import tensorflow module in python
due to this error

```
Python 2.7.15rc1 (default, Apr 15 2018, 21:51:34) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/kai/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/home/kai/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/home/kai/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kai/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/kai/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/kai/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: libcudnn.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

but I think I correctly put those at the right place like below show

```
$ cd /usr/local/cuda/lib64
:/usr/local/cuda/lib64$ ls -l libcudnn*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 287624224 May 15 19:01 libcudnn.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 287624224 May 15 19:01 libcudnn.so.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 287624224 May 15 19:01 libcudnn.so.7.0.5
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 280805558 May 15 19:02 libcudnn_static.a
```

so now I wonder why this happen

thanks to read this

Comment: did you do export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64
export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda

Comment: if this is still an issue - recommend checking my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/61563579/1215913 it looks like you have the same issue as me - the symbolic links are broken..

Answer (score 5):

solved by

sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit

don't know why there isn't the tip for this at official site