# Tensorflow import error: libcudnn.so.5 No such file or directory

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I am trying to work with `tensorflow-gpu==1.2.0` in google-colab.
I did install the package, cuda-8.0 and download and move libcudnn.so.5 into /usr/local/cuda/lib64 and still I get this error:

```
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 29, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 25, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: libcudnn.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried to follow the next solution:
[ImportError: libcudnn when running a TensorFlow program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41991101/importerror-libcudnn-when-running-a-tensorflow-program)
But it does not work for me. 
I would be happy to get some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file cannot be found, it's not in a place the linker is looking.

From the [ld man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ld):

> The linker uses the following search paths to locate required shared libraries:
>
> 1. Any directories specified by -rpath-link options.
> 2. Any directories specified by -rpath options. The difference between -rpath and -rpath-link is that directories specified by -rpath options are included in the executable and used at runtime, whereas the -rpath-link option is only effective at link time. Searching -rpath in this way is only supported by native linkers and cross linkers which have been configured with the --with-sysroot option.
> 3. On an ELF system, for native linkers, if the -rpath and -rpath-link options were not used, search the contents of the environment variable "LD_RUN_PATH".
> 4. On SunOS, if the -rpath option was not used, search any directories specified using -L options.
> 5. For a native linker, the search the contents of the environment variable "LD_LIBRARY_PATH".
> 6. For a native ELF linker, the directories in "DT_RUNPATH" or "DT_RPATH" of a shared library are searched for shared libraries needed by it. The "DT_RPATH" entries are ignored if "DT_RUNPATH" entries exist.
> 7. The default directories, normally /lib and /usr/lib.
> 8. For a native linker on an ELF system, if the file /etc/ld.so.conf exists, the list of directories found in that file.
>
> If the required shared library is not found, the linker will issue a warning and continue with the link.

Also see [ldconfig man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ldconfig):

> ldconfig creates the necessary links and cache to the most recent shared libraries found in the directories specified on the command line, in the file /etc/ld.so.conf, and in the trusted directories (/lib and /usr/lib). The cache is used by the run-time linker, ld.so or ld-linux.so. ldconfig checks the header and filenames of the libraries it encounters when determining which versions should have their links updated.
>
> ...
>
> ## Options
>
> ### -v
>
> Verbose mode. Print current version number, the name of each directory as it is scanned, and any links that are created. Overrides quiet mode.

Comment: Thank you! Based on your answer I did add the libcudnn5 files to the /lib and create a soft link to libcudnn.so.5 in the /lib directory and it did resolve the problem.